# Discrete Dirichlet problem has a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, harmonic-functions, finite-differences

I am studying Artin's *Algebra*. In Chapter 1 Exercise M11, he asks to show that every discrete Dirichlet problem on a finite discrete set in plane has a unique solution. This is essentially the question:

> Let $R$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{ Z\times Z}$. Let $\partial R$ be the set of all the points, not in $R$, which are unit distance away from some point in $R$. Let $\beta$ be a function on $\partial R$. Then we need to show that there exists a unique function $f$ on $R\cup \partial R$ such that $f(u, v) = \beta_{u, v}$ for all $(u, v)\in\partial R$ and that $f$ satisfies the discrete Laplace equation$^1$ for all points in $R$.

The full question can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3629048/673223).

**My attempt at solving this:**

After arbitrarily ordering $R$, we get a linear system $LX = B$ to solve for $X$ where $B$ contains combinations of $\beta_{u, v}$'s. We just need to show that any such $L$ is invertible, or equivalently, has a nonzero determinant.

I abstracted out the following properties that any coefficient matrix $L$ must satisfy (possibly after a rearrangement of equations, provided that we write the equations as mentioned in the footnote):

1. The diagonal entries are all $4$.
2. Nondiagonal entries can be either $0$ or $-1$.
3. Any row can have at most four $-1$ entries (since any point in $R$ can have at most four points in $\partial R$ that are a unit distance away from it).
4. Any column in $L$ can also have a maximum of four $-1$ entries (since any point in $R$ can be a unit distance away from at most four points in $R$).

Now I consider an arbitrary matrix $A$ satisfying the above properties. I rearrange the columns and rows (by elementary row and column operations) to get the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
B & \ast\\
\ast & B'
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here $B$ and $B'$ are matrices satisfying the above properties, with the additional condition on $B'$: its first column is entirely nonzero, and contains all the $-1$'s of the first column of the original $A$. Thus $b'$ has size at most $5\times 5$ and at least $1\times 1$. By induction, we can row reduce $B'$ to $I$, and thus we can row reduce $A$ to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
B' & 0\\
\ast & I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now all I need to show is that $B'$ is also invertible. The brute force method contains $2^{20}$ cases with the general matrix to be analyzed for invertibility being
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & &\ast\\
&\ddots&\\
\ast&&4
\end{bmatrix}_{5\times 5}
$$
with the nondiagonal entries being $-1$ or $0$. (This case will also suffice for the cases when $B$ has a smaller size.)

But I am unable to prove this base case without brute force.

**Can you help?**

---

$^1$$f$ satisfies the Laplace equation at $(u, v)\in R$ iff $4f(u, v) = f(u+1, v) + f(u-1, v) + f(u, v+1) + f(u, v-1)$.

Comment: I think the existence is often tackled by considering the [Dirichlet form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_form) or [random walks](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001057). I haven't thought about purely algebraic approach, though...